# Windows 365. User-assigned Managed Identity

Tags: azure-identity

We would like to run some PowerShell scripts inside Windows 365 workstations that authenticate to Azure in a secure way. I'm not able to find how to apply user-assigned managed identity to Windows 365 VMs like we do to our Azure VMs. Is that not possible?